# fwrite and strcat truncating string and writing nonsense values

Tags: c, fwrite, strcat

When the function shown below is called it write certain parts of the string to a text file. it will sometimes remove characters, so lightning strike number will come out as "ghtning strik number". It has never properly displayed the strike number as a character, it always comes out at "lightning strike number:". I think the problem may be with strcat, but I can't figure out exactly why, any help would be appreciated.

```
void recordLightningStrike( int strikeNumber, char fileName[], FILE *filePointer )
{
   time_t systemTime;
   struct tm *UTCTime;

   char numberOfStrikes[6];
   char strikeTime[24];
   char stringOne[25];
   char stringTwo[55];
   //char finalString[200];

   itoa( strikeNumber, numberOfStrikes, 10 );
   time( &systemTime );
   UTCTime = localtime( &systemTime );
   strcpy( strikeTime, asctime( UTCTime ) );
   strcpy( stringOne, "Lightning Strike Number: " );
   strcpy( stringTwo, "Lightning Strike Occurred at: " );
   strcat( stringOne, numberOfStrikes );
   strcat( stringTwo, strikeTime );
   //strcpy( finalString, stringOne );
   //strcat( finalString, stringTwo );
   printf( " %s %c ", stringOne, '\n' );
   FILE *openPointer = fopen( fileName, "a" );
   if( openPointer!=NULL )
   {
      fwrite( stringOne, sizeof(char), sizeof(stringOne), openPointer );
      fwrite( stringTwo, sizeof(char), sizeof(stringTwo), openPointer );
   }
   fclose( openPointer );  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare both buffers (stringOne and stringTwo) bigger. And don't use `sizeof()` but `strlen`. Also, for the sake of performance, write each buffer at once, by swapping the arguments `size` and `count` (actually, computing the buffer size and writing `1` buffer):

```
.
.
.
char stringOne[50]; // guess; you could compute it more tightly
char stringTwo[60]; // guess; you could compute it more tightly
.
.
.
fwrite( stringOne, sizeof(char) * strlen(stringOne), 1, openPointer );
fwrite( stringTwo, sizeof(char) * strlen(stringTwo), 1, openPointer );
.
.
.
```

The above adjustments will probably correct your program. But you could make it easier to read, using `snprintf()` to print to the buffer or, even better, `fprintf()` to print directly to the `FILE*`:

```
fprintf( openPointer, "Lightning Strike Number: %d\n", strikeNumber );
fprintf( openPointer, "Lightning Strike Occurred at: %s\n", asctime( UTCTime ) );
```

Comment: Your suggestion for using strlen fixed the junk values problem, however, even when I increased the size of stringOne to 60 to the number of strikes still failed to appear. Using fprintf, however, solved the issue, thank you. If you have any insight as to why fwrite didn't work, that would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

strcat won't resize your character array, so the line

```
strcat( stringOne, numberOfStrikes );
```

overflows the array and the number is not stored. Try increasing the size of stringOne by a few slots.

Answer (score 0):

`stringOne` doesn't have enough space in it. The initial string you copy to it (`"Lightning Strike Number: "`) already overflows the buffer of 25 chars since the string is 26 characters, including the terminating zero-character. Then you `strcat` even more to it. Don't make your string sizes so small.